# Get the Installtion Path From ClickOnce Deployment

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, clickonce, office-addins

I need to get the installation path of the clickOnce app.

The path: 
**C:\Users\lenovo\AppData\Local\Apps\2.0\LEGRGER7.57W\4Z5LN4OT.J7H\MyApp..vsto_c3da112430e41901_0001.0000_2214160f1f9567c9**

Anyway my intention is to add a file(.tagger) to the ClickOnce installer and read that file from code. but I couldn't save the file in to my predefined location of client machine.

So I go through to read that installation path and then copy that file in to my custom folder location somewhere else at the first run of my application.

Currently I did this but could get the data path not the installation file path.

```
 string sourcePath = System.Deployment.Application.ApplicationDeployment.CurrentDeployment.DataDirectory;
```

Any other way to do this or same approach can I do it another way around?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use this code :

For get your path :

```
    string sourcePath =System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location
```

For opening automaticuly your path installation :

```
  System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("explorer.exe", AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory)
```

Comment: The first path returns the pathC:\Users\lenovo\AppData\Local\assembly\dl3\HW47O5YM.1B1\4AZBEZH6.74H\6bfae6b6\f865bf5c_6f9cd101\, But i need the path  C:\Users\lenovo\AppData\Local\Apps\2.0\LEGRGER7.57W\4Z5LN4OT.J7H\MyApp..vsto_c3da112430e41901_0001.0000_2214160f1f9567c9\

Comment: If you have a solution how containts a ClassLibrary . you must past the code in the project "exe"

Comment: I got the path using AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory. Seems it is ok.but let me know please what is the use of System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("explorer.exe", AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory).Thank You.

Comment: This is for openning the local directory ,you can ignor it.if it is ok please mark that the issus is solved